# how I can I set iptables to only allow certain mac addresses to connect to connect to a server

Tags: networking, debian, firewall, iptables

I am currently attempting to configure iptables to only allow certain mac addresses to connect it (this is a debian machine being used as a router) in order to provide a small level of protection to prevent people from connecting to my network without my knowledge (live in a dorm room, worried about the possibility of my roommate connecting to it), but am having difficulty getting the mac address blocking to work at all (when i make the changes, the servers continues to operate as i had before), without any changed added for blocking mac addresses, this is my regular configuration

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Sep 12 23:56:43 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5151384:752742780]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [969:251840]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [97167:7471385]
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 12 23:56:43 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Wed Sep 12 23:56:43 2012
*filter
:INPUT DROP [4858214:733505988]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 192.167.1.0/24 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 12 23:56:43 2012
```

although i've tried a few different solutions so far, I have yet to find anything that will work, if someone could offer advice or push me in the right direction for this though I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: There is no expression filtering matching mac addresses ? Is it normal ? Did you read the man page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for MAC address filtering is

```
iptables -I "CHAIN-NAME" -m mac --mac-source "MAC-ADDRESS" -j "ACTION"
```